# FontAwesome Not Displaying

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, font-awesome

I'm trying to get FontAwesome (v5) working using MVC5 bundling. Everything works fine on Chrome/Fx, but in IE, although the Network panel in dev tools shows the font file and css are loaded, I just get a blank space where the icon should be. It looks like something is overriding the font-awesome style, though I can't see it. I've tried changing the cache and pragma settings in web.config with no effect.

[image: Developer tools]

Comment: Are you using the old FontAwesome classes? Try `<i class="fas fa-home"></i>` for example

Comment: This is the latest version of FA. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome though.

Comment: The newer FontAwesome uses different classes than you are showing. Note the `fas` class has replaced `fa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by removing some custom headers from `web.config`:

```
<add name="cache-control" value="no-store,no-cache" />
<add name="pragma" value="no-store,no-cache" />
```

Answer (score 1):

IE (Classic, not sure of Edge) has security settings around the downloading of fonts within a web page.  You can either

a) Add your site to the "Trusted Sites" or

b) change your security settings to allow Font Downloads (however, this will take place across all sites in the zone that you are modifying this setting for.

To change this setting, click the gear/cog icon in the top right of IE and select `Internet Options`.  From here, click the `Security` tab and either add your site to Trusted Sites or click the `Custom Level` box and verify/modify the Font Download attribute section.

**Note** - In corporate environments, this setting can be overruled using Group Policy and the Trusted Sites option may be the only path to allow the font download.

[image]

Another possibility is that IE is set to some old version compatibility mode.  To ensure IE is running in a mode that will support `FontAwesome`, you can also add a meta tag to your site to force IE to render with the correct engine (the line below tells IE to run at its highest rendering engine version).

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`